# How long could a sealed room/building smolder and still be capable of a backdraft/flashover when reopened?

Tags: physics, materials, fire, crime

As a hypothetical, say a bad dude decides he needs to burn a home for some reason, but doesn't want the fire to be immediately spotted and responded to.  He gets the house sealed up to the point where the fire has burned some of his problems, has now used up most of the oxygen, and is smoldering away.

If he sets up some automatic rig to break a window after a set period, how long could it reasonably delayed to where the fire will still reignite when air is reintroduced?

I realize this question probably has way too many variables to get anything super accurate, but a ballpark would be great.  Are we talking a couple hours of holding enough heat to flare back up, a day or two?

Comment: Maybe hours. If you were simply trying to hold back incineration you could stage it to not flare up for weeks, but fire needs fuel to burn and you stated that "some of his problems" had already been consumed, which means the fire is fundamentally uncontrolled other than by oxygen deprivation. The fire will burn into spaces with tons of oxygen - like the attic - and will eventually burn a hole through a wall. That's not predictable. Do you need a sciencey answer? Why is [narrative necessity](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7281/40609) inadequate for your needs?

Comment: Mostly just a matter of trying to keep a foot in the door of reality.  It's mainly an idea for him to be able to plausibly be away from the scene when it become impossible for others not to notice, which will require some fiddling in the first place, as the beginning burn will still need some factors for it to go unnoticed for a period of time.  Mainly just trying to figure out how much time, realistically, he could work with if we assume the first part managed to go unnoticed. So I can work with hours or days, but would rather aim for whichever one is closer to reality.

Comment: Cool. For future reference, please remember to be as specific as possible. "How long can I do this?" is a much harder, much more ambiguous question to ask than "I need to do it X fast, how can I rationalize that?" New users (and authors) often prefer the former question style (which isn't preferred by Stack Exchange) to "keep their options open." Useful for you, painful for us. It's better to make the choice than to hope for the best.

Answer (score 3):

From what I read, flashover occurs when the heat at ceiling height is roughly 1,100°F for ordinary room materials. It could be higher or lower for unconventional materials, depending on their combustion points. Also, for a fire to smolder over time it needs a limited source of fresh oxygen, so the room cannot be completely sealed. Technically speaking, a well-informed and well-prepared arsonist could prolong flashover indefinitely, limited only by:

- a fuel supply sufficient to smolder for the period of time desired at an appropriate temperature
- a properly controlled source of fresh oxygen to keep the smolder from dropping too low or peaking too high

Honestly, anyone who's done research into flashovers has likely done this within a laboratory environment, so it's perfectly possible. It's just a bit difficult to apply to uncontrolled real-world environments.

If your question is about someone doing this without special equipment or controls — just with the materials on hand in a random room — I'd say two hours would be an outside, with a large error term. It takes a while for a room to get hot enough for flashover, and if the fire isn't carefully constructed it could burn through a containing floor, wall, or ceiling, sparking a premature flashover or releasing enough heat to drop the air below flashover point. Rooms just aren't consistent enough for *ad hoc* arson to be predictable this way.

Comment: Yeah, I definitely realize a lot has to be taken with grace given how many variables are in the mix.  Thank you for narrowing down for me.  I can certainly put the character where they'd need to be in either time frame, I just want to keep a thread of plausibility involved, hence wondering what sort of time frame would be possible.  I'm no expert in fires, despite some of my misspent youth, so just wanted a bit of a boundary to go by.

Answer (score 2):

## For years

There is a thing called [peat fire](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peat#Peat_fires), which can last for years and produce yearly [zombie fires](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holdover_fire) which are impossible to fully extinguish. So, hypothetically speaking, one can set up a contraption fueled with peat and wait until the right time arrives.

Comment: Thanks for that, will definitely read more about those, could be useful!

Comment: For years in an enclosed house? Smoke would set off the smoke detectors and eventually choke out the flame. So it can't be years. Are there any citations about how quickly smoke replaces free oxygen in an enclosed space? That would indicate how long this could really last.

Comment: The wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peat#Peat_fires page has it all. If you have block of peat big enough, then it will burn slowly and very stealthy. No smoke until it fully ignites

Comment: I read the link. "In the summer of 2010, an unusually high heat wave of up to 40 °C (104 °F) ignited large deposits of peat in Central Russia, burning thousands of houses and covering the capital of Moscow with a **toxic smoke blanket.**" There must be enough heat to meet the OP's expectation: "The fire has burned some of his problems, has now used up most of the oxygen, and is smoldering away." I suspect you're basing your answer on "or smoulder underground and reignite after winter if an oxygen source is present." But oxy must exist to smoulder. So I still think years isn't factual. ...

Comment: ... However, it would really help if the OP explained how long they need the house to smoulder before reignition and finishing the job. The reignition itself could be caused by someone opening the door... but that's a high risk of discovery of the crime. Unless peat flashes?

Comment: @JBH, I might be wrong, but the oxygen for smoldering in case of the peat is not from the atmosphere. Otherwise it would be impossible for it to burn underground for long periods of time. The peat is used as fuel, so maybe there was a pile in the house that did not fully ignite or burned partially. It might trigger after years if somebody disturbs it. It is a long shot, but technically possible

Comment: @FrogOfJuly the peat is burning with oxygen it is just burning it very slowly. peat is a dense but porous material, it is burning as fast as oxygen can infiltrate it. because peat is a very good insulator the heat can't escape quickly so it stays at combustion temperature. Its a vey poor model for a house.

Answer (score 1):

This is a fun one. My guess: one hour.  Here are the variables, as I understand it. Disclaimer: I am not a firefighter.

In order to have blowback, you need to have a minimum surface area maintained at smoldering temperature. The time limitations are either:

- you burn through all of your material, or
- the material cools off, or
- you burn through to an oxygen-providing space, like the next room or outdoors

Thus, you have to keep the material at the right temperature by providing it with enough oxygen to keep it self-heating.

[This paper](https://www.frontiersin.org/articles/10.3389/fmech.2021.686638/full) was produced while trying to figure out how long trees would keep smoldering after a wild fire, so I figured it would provide us with good base data. It states that the heat of smoldering conducts through wood at a rate of around 4 mm per minute. At that rate, you'll get from one side of a 3.5 inch 2x4 in about 20 minutes, assuming an even burn.

If you start your smolder in the middle of a floor, the surface area of burning material will increase over time. If you presume a consistent oxygen feed, it will eventually cool off. Maybe the room is the right size for it to start crawling up the walls before that happens, but then you have twenty minutes before it gets outside and sucks in enough oxygen.

So, overall, maybe an hour if you actually want enough surface area to cause blowback.